How to import 3D (animated) models in Java
I'm relatively new to Java and I was wanting to make a 3D game after successfully making a 2D game. I've started to learn 3D modeling with Blender and now I am wondering how to import these models into Java or JavaFX or any other ways. Added bonus if there is a way to import animated models somehow, I can't really wrap my head around how that would work currently.
Haven't tried much at this point, just wondering how to get started.
Thanks!

I would suggest you take the time to investigate available 3d gaming engines, like LWJGL and libGDX for example. As to your question, no, there is no "native" support available for what you're trying to achieve, although there does seem to be some discussion around the topic
